# xsl-fo: Auto resize font size in a fixed cell

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf, xsl-fo

I have a cell with fixed height and I want the font size of the text inside to reduce accordingly with the amount of text inside cell.

**UPDATE:**

Sorry. But I thought you will understand what is the problem. I'm trying to modify some xslt pattern which used to create PDF document from XML. And I have to make document to print on some blank. Unfortunately I've got limited space, and somehow I have to locete data from XML on this space. For convenience I use table. And I have to locate data in cells with fixed height and width. If data longer then I expected cell height increases. I whant somehow avoid it. But I heve to keep all data, so I can't use wrap. And I thought that it will be cool to do auto resize font-size.

Comment: I want a red Ferrari that I can call my own .. What is your actual question? What have you tried so far? Is anything in particular not working as expected? ...

Comment: I want to resize font in the cell with fixed height if content longer then expected.

Comment: Again you're not being very detailed. And responding to your clarification: isn't it a cell with fixed width if it's the length of the content that makes you want to reduce the font size if necessary? Also, do you want to reduce as much as possible, or is there a limit? .. Moreover, are you doing stuff in Java / .Net / any other language? Or is this done in an XML tool like Oxygen? .. I'm aware that you might not find my reactions very friendly but my intention is merely to get the question to a level where people can actually help you find an answer.

Comment: Sorry. But I thought you will understand what is the problem.
I'm trying to modify some  xslt pattern which used to create PDF document from XML. And I have to make document to print on some blank. Unfortunately I've got limited space, and somehow I have to locete data from XML on this space. For convenience I use table. And I have to locate data in cells with fixed height and width. If data longer then I expected cell height increases. I whant somehow avoid it. But I heve to keep all data, so I can't use wrap. And I thought that it will be cool to do auto resize font-size.

Comment: I've edited your question with this clarification. It's a bit clearer now what your situation is and what you're trying to do. Let's see if anyone - I'll look too when I find some time - can come up with any suggestions. Meanwhile consider how your table within the pdf might look if you have certain cells with reduced fonts. You might not like the outcome of that.

Comment: You're right, it will not look good. Sometimes, perhaps, it will be difficult to make out what written, but as I see this I have to do just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out some interesting way to do it. It is not automatic way to do it but it helps me to resolve my problems.

```
<x:variable name="NDSPercent" select="./NDSPercent"/>
<x:if test="string-length($NDSPercent) &lt; 3">
  <fo:block>
    <x:value-of select="$NDSPercent"/>
  </fo:block>
</x:if>
<x:if test="string-length($NDSPercent) &gt; 3">
  <fo:block font-size="8pt">
    <x:value-of select="$NDSPercent"/>
  </fo:block>
</x:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Print and Page Layout Community Group @ W3C has produced some extension functions for running the FO processor within your XSLT to get an area tree so you can make decisions based on formatted areas.

Your use sounds like the "Copyfitting by adjusting 'font-size'" example at http://www.w3.org/community/ppl/wiki/XSLTExtensions#Example_5_-_Copyfitting_by_adjusting_.27font-size.27

Here's the then-current PPL CG description text sized to fill a box:

[image: PPL CG description sized to fill a box]

If you use Antenna House's AH Formatter, you may be able to use its overflow extensions to get AH Formatter to size the text for you.  See the multiple extension properties at http://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf60/docs/ahf-ext.html#ext-overflow